# SqlNotificationEvents with signalR causes to fire multiple times?

Tags: sql-server, ajax, asp.net-mvc, signalr, sqldependency

I am newbie for using signalr in asp.net mvc project to catch user notifications. I followed [these steps](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/874240/SignalR-Database-update-notifications-in-ASP-NET-M)

Here is my ajax call

```
$(function () {

        // Proxy created on the fly
        var job = $.connection.ntfHub;

        // Declare a function on the job hub so the server can invoke it
        job.client.displayStatus = function () {
            toastr.warning("1 Bildirim Alındı!");
            getData();
        };

        // Start the connection
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            console.log("connection started")
            getData();
        }).fail(function (e) {
            alert(e);
        });
    });

    function getData() {
        var tbl = $("#header_notification_bar")
         $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("GetNtf","Home")',
            contentType: 'application/html ; charset:utf-8',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'html'
        }).success(function (result) {
            tbl.empty().append(result);
            console.log("called");
        }).error(function () {

        });


    }
```

and here is my SQL query

```
SELECT 
    [nu].[NtU_ID], [n].[Ntf_Title], [n].[Ntf_Description],
    [u].[Usr_NameSurname], [n].[Ntf_Date] 
FROM 
    [dbo].[SysNotificationUser] nu 
INNER JOIN  
    [dbo].[SysUser] u ON [nu].[NtU_UserID] = [u].[ID] 
INNER JOIN 
    [dbo].[SysNotifications] n ON [nu].[NtU_NtfID] = [n].[Ntf_ID] 
WHERE 
    [nu].[NtU_UserID] = 2 
    AND [nu].[NtU_IsRead] = 0
```

The other issues about using signalr like startup class are same as in the tutorial.

There is something strange situation first time the change happens ajax making 1 call but other changes # of ajax call getting bigger and bigger. It doesn't make 1 call for 1 change except first time. For example in console, for the first time there is only one "called" but after that like 8 times "called" 16 times "called" and so on.

In repository

```
private void dependency_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Type == SqlNotificationType.Change)
        {
            NtfHub.Show();
        }

    }
```

and Hub class

```
public void Hello()
    {
        Clients.All.hello();
    }
    [HubMethodName("show")]
    public static void Show()
    {
        IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<NtfHub>();
        context.Clients.All.displayStatus();
    }
```

Method for execute command

```
 public List<PopulateNtfBar> GetData()
    {

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ConnectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT [NtU_ID] FROM [dbo].[SysNotificationUser] WHERE [NtU_UserID] =2 AND [NtU_IsRead] = 0", connection))
            {
                // Make sure the command object does not already have
                // a notification object associated with it.
                command.Notification = null;

                SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
                dependency.OnChange += dependency_OnChange;

                if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    connection.Open();
                    command.ExecuteScalar();

            }

            using (SqlCommand command2 = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT [nu].[NtU_ID],[n].[Ntf_Title],[n].[Ntf_Description],[u].[Usr_NameSurname],[n].[Ntf_Date] FROM [dbo].[SysNotificationUser] nu INNER JOIN [dbo].[SysUser] u ON [nu].[NtU_UserID]=[u].[ID] INNER JOIN [dbo].[SysNotifications] n ON [nu].[NtU_NtfID]=[n].[Ntf_ID] WHERE [nu].[NtU_UserID] =2 AND [nu].[NtU_IsRead] = 0", connection))
            {
                using (var reader = command2.ExecuteReader())
                    return reader.Cast<IDataRecord>()
                        .Select(item => new PopulateNtfBar()
                        {
                            Description = item["Ntf_Description"].ToString(),
                            Title = item["Ntf_Title"].ToString(),
                            TimeDiff = FindDifferenceTime(Convert.ToDateTime(item["Ntf_Date"]))
                        }).ToList();


            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: How and where do you trigger job.client.displayStatus?

Comment: @MarcusH i edited the question

Comment: Just a detail: tbl.empty().append(result); = tbl.html(result).

Comment: In your server side method Show: You could send the html as a parameter in displayStatus(html) and skip the ajax call for the html from the client. then you can skip one call to the server and your site will work faster.

Comment: @MarcusH Can you please explain your answer in details?Does it remove multiple call?

Comment: No, this does not remove your error. I just gave you a tip on how you could make your code more effective with signalR.
When you debug your code, How many times does dependency_OnChange get triggered when an update in the databse is done?

Comment: when I rebuild and run programme it is only triggered once, but after every update or insert, it is called several times incremented exponentially! on second insert, it is called once, on third insert, it is called four times, on fourth insert, it is called eight times and so on.

Comment: Ok, Could you please share your SqlCommand where you execute the query in c#?

Comment: I updated my question with the method. @MarcusH

Comment: I have no idea how to fixed this but it's not a SignalR problem. This has to do with your streaming for SqlNotificationEvent in the DB. You should change your title to reach more advanced programers on SqlNotificationEvents

Comment: Thanks for response.